# How to setup and connect Teletalk 3g modem in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, connection, modem

I am very fond of Linux and recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. 
I am having issues trying to connect my Teletalk 3g modem in Ubuntu 14.04 for mobile broadband.

If anyone could provide step by step instructions on how to set this up, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the context of the file and find a line that says `Exec=Teletalk_3G` and change it to `Exec=gksudo "Teletalk_3G"`

Now you can find this Teletalk_3G entry in the menu->Internet->Teletalk 3G. Run from there and connect to internet.

N.B: It will ask for root password every time you run it.

Installing in Ubuntu 64 bit:

You first need to install `ia32-libs` in ubuntu. If you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS then you won't find this in the repo. For that case run these codes:

```
sudo -i
apt-get install gksu
dpkg --add-architecture i386
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
rm ia32-libs-raring.list
```

Now you can follow the instructions for installing in Linux Mint (#1) from above

Comment: I followed this but not work. see this https://pasteboard.co/GZ0Yc7R.png  https://pasteboard.co/GZ0YRiU.png